# An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context in Angular8

Tags: angular, build, angular8, ambient

I get this error and I've tried with `update @angular/core & @angular/material` changed version in package.json file as well yet it didn't fix this issue.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Spa  services[0]
>         ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts:133:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVRbm.png)

Comment: Please add the error messages directly to the question (as code/text) instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Which command did you use?